Why is the datatype none returned here?
I just wrote a very simple code, but I don't understand the output.
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = x.append(x[0])
print(y)

and it prints 'none' as the result.
Why is the final result 'none'? I snooped and saw that the append function did work, but the new list wasn't given to y.

Why is the final result 'none'? Because that's how .append() works.  It does NOT return a new list.  It updates the actual list, and then returns None.

The append method in python returns None.
It does not return the mutated object unlike other languages.
This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.
document

You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default None. 1 This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

